# How to set Cache headers for images in Azure Blob Storage (Please note I didnt take Azure CDN)

Tags: azure, local-storage, blob

Is there a way to set up Cache headers for Images in Azure Blob Storage - Please Suggest - we have around 2M images wanted to add Maxage . I tried Powershell solutions but it says Properties not exist Null refrence error giving...

Is there a work around to set it up ?

Please advise , thank you !!

**Edited:**

**Powershell Script :**

```
#connection info
$StorageName="storagename given here"
$StorageKey="Key Replaced here”
$ContainerName="container name given here" 
$BlobUri="added correct URI here"+$ContainerName

#get all the blob under your container
$StorageCtx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageName -StorageAccountKey $StorageKey
$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $StorageCtx 

#creat CloudBlobClient
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9\ref\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll"
$storageCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey -ArgumentList $StorageName,$StorageKey
$blobClient =   New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlobClient($BlobUri,$storageCredentials)

#set Properties and Metadata
$cacheControlValue = "public, max-age=60480"
foreach ($blob in $blobs)
{
   $blobRef = $blobClient.GetBlobReference($blob.Name) 

   #set Properties
   $blobRef.Properties.CacheControl = $cacheControlValue
   $blobRef.SetProperties()
}
```

Comment: Please share your PowerShell code.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, Thank you for your quick reply, I have updated the code above. Please check.

Comment: The above code actually works - we found there were few images without any extensions - which were causing the problem and the code unable to set headers for those and throw Null reference error message.  So, thank you !